# Discord.py - on_message stops my commands from working

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have a modmail bot (with some light moderation commands) and it all works for me except when I add an on_message event

I've already tried everything I could find (including `await client.process_commands(message)`) but nothing worked

I have on_ready & on_message

````
async def on_ready():
 print ('                              ================================================')
 print ('                                            Bot is now online!')
 print ('')
 print ('                                            Logged in as:')
 print ('                                            {0.user}'.format(client))
 print ('')
 print ('                                            Working on:')
 print (f'                                            {len(client.guilds)} servers!')
 print ('                              ================================================')
 await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name="My DM's | DM for help!"))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
 if message.author !=client.user and isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
  log_channel=client.get_channel(0000000000000)
  await log_channel.send(f"ID: {message.author.id} - "
  + f"**{message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator}:**"
  + f"```{message.content}```")
  await client.process_commands(message)
````

I might be doing something wrong but if I remove the `on_message` it works but if I don't have that then I won't be able to answer the modmail
(where I have `log_channel=client.get_channel(0000000000000)` I have the channel ID, just not showing it here)

Comment: anyone know how to fix it or something?

Comment: check the indentation of `process_commands`.  It looks like you have it inside the `if`, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I'm so annoyed at that, it worked, thx, I'm so stupid sometimes, sry